# How long does it normally take for the iCloud drive to set its self up?

Tags: mac, icloud

I’ve been waiting for my outdated MacBook (early 2009 model) to finish ‘setting up iCloud Drive.’ I have 749GB of stuff in iCould and I set up the computer to do this over night, but st some point it lost internet…

Comment: How fast is your internet connection? 750GB is a significant quantity of data, even over a fast line. https://www.download-time.com

Comment: @Tetsujin My download speed is close to 100Mbit/s

Comment: Then about 18 hours, at 'perfect' speed, if nothing slows it down.

Comment: There are two setup steps - one is based on how many files you have and the other on your file sizes. The file sizes (file downloading) will show you a progress bar. Until you see a progress bar though, it can take up to a full day. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333235/icloud-drive-not-downloading-files-after-reset/339680#339680

Comment: Oof. that’s going to take for ever. Thank you for the help!